# Set theory and Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a group of 70 cars tested by a garage in Delhi, 15 had faulty tyres, 20 had faulty brakes and 18 exceed the allowable emission limits. Also, 5 cars had faulty tyres and breaks, 6 failed on tyres and emission limits, 10 failed on breaks and emission, and 4 cars were unsatisfactory in all aspects, how many had no fault in these 3 checks?

Comment: Hi Buchi, welcome to MSE! What have you tried? This is not a forum where people just do your HW for you. Please see
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960
The Venn diagram approach you allude to in the title is a good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, we have 70 total subtract 15+20+18=53, giving 17. Then add back the overlaps of any 2 as they got subtracted twice, 6+10+5+17=38. Now deal with the threeway overlap, it got subtracted 3 times (not the 6 I thought, because the overlaps overlap), then added back 3 times. We need to subtract it once more. 38-4=34.  34 cars had no fault when checked,70-34=36 did. Next time show what's been tried, and the problem source.

Comment: Are you taking 4 as the 3 overlaps? I thought they said 4 were unsatisfactory in all 3 aspects? Isn’t it meant to be excluded from all the three aspects?

Comment: no, it means standards were not satified in all three areas.

Comment: okay found a slight error in my math, but you can use this method for arbitrarily many sets.

Comment: Is there a way I can  snap my Venn diagram and the question and send you here?

Comment: hit the add image option in your original post.

Comment: It says I need at least 10 reputation to post an image, I joined yesterday.

Comment: okay gain upthose reputation points, you can get them fairly easily, 1 upvoted answer to someone else's question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you start from the middle, (4 unsatisfied all) and work your way out.

Answer is 34 cars

edit: the question states 4 cars unsatisfied all three categories. If a car is being tested in a garage and it fails the test, this means the test was unsatisfied

Comment: I’m so happy you could solve this, but can you explain?

Comment: I’ve been having issue with the unsatisfied. I just edited the question to exactly how it was in my test(basically the unsatisfactory). When it said unsatisfactory in all three aspects, doesn’t it mean the 4 were faulty, but couldn’t fall under any of the 3 faults. So I put the 4 outside the circle. If it was to be in the middle of the 3, I felt the statement would have been, “and 4 satisfied all 3 aspects). I hope you get my issue.